# .pack('B*') in Ruby 1.8 vs. 2.2

Tags: ruby

I'm working with a Ruby 1.8 based gem that relies heavily on the `pack` method. Running the following on different Ruby versions, yields different results:

```
["0"].pack("B*")
```

In Ruby 1.8.7 I get `"\000"` as a result. In Ruby 2.2.0 I get `"\x00"`. How would I go about getting the same results in 2.2 as in 1.8?

Comment: It's the same result, just displayed differently in the console when you have unprintable characters (Ruby 1.8 shows octal character code, Ruby 2.2 shows hex - they are both showing you a single 0 value byte). Try `["01111000"].pack("B*")` in both  . . . should be `"x"`

Comment: @NeilSlater that explains a lot. Thank you very much!